# not able to replace spring bean with mock in camel route

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

using @Profile I am able to mock the spring bean, however in the camel route which mock bean method is not invoked. I am using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class and using @ActiveProfile
Below is the route in which I want to replace, cancelSubscriptionTransformer, myBeanClient, extendedClient beans with my mock beans in unit testing.

```
from("{{cancelSubscriptionFromRMQUri}}").routeId("cancelSubscriptionRoute")
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Subscription.class)
            .bean("cancelSubscriptionTransformer", "toKbCancelSubscription")
            .choice()
            .when().simple("${body.serviceType} == 'subscriptions'")
            .bean("myBeanClient", "cancelSubscription(${body.subscriptionId}, ${body.createdBy}, ${body.reason}, ${body.comment})")
            .bean("extendedClient", "retrieveSubscription(${body.subscriptionId}, ${body.externalKey})")
            .marshal(json)
            .to("{{cancelSubscriptionTORMQUri}}")
            .when().simple("${body.serviceType} == 'usage'")
            .bean("myBeanClient", "cancelSubscription(${body.subscriptionId}, ${body.dateTime},null, null, -1, ${body.createdBy}, ${body.reason}," +
                    " ${body.comment})")
            .endChoice();
```

Below is how I define my ExtendedClientMock, I use the same approach for the rest of the mock beans

```
@Profile("test")
@Primary
@Repository
public class ExtendedClientMock  extends ExtendedClient {

public Subscription retrieveSubscription(UUID subscriptionid, String sdpSubscriptionId) throws MyClientException {
    Subscription subs=new Subscription();
    subs.setProductName("test");
    return subs;
}
}
```

Below is the code for unit testing:

```
  @ActiveProfiles({"test", "aop"})
  @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @SpringBootTest(classes = CancelSubscriptionRouteTest.class)
  @EnableAutoConfiguration
  @ComponentScan
  @ContextConfiguration(classes = { BillingServicesApplication.class })
  @UseAdviceWith

  public class CancelSubscriptionRouteTest {

  @Autowired
  protected CamelContext camelContext;

  @Autowired
  private CancelSubscriptionTransformer cancelSubscriptionTransformer;

  @Autowired
  private ExtendedClient extendedClient;

  @Autowired
  private MyBeanClient myBeanClient;

  @EndpointInject(uri = "{{cancelSubscriptionTORMQUri}}")
  private MockEndpoint cancelSubscriptionTORMQUriEndpoint;

  @EndpointInject(uri = "{{cancelSubscriptionFromRMQUri}}")
  private ProducerTemplate cancelSubscriptionFromRMQUriEndpoint;

  @Inject
  private ObjectMapperContextResolver objectMapperContextResolver;

  @Test
  @DirtiesContext
  public void testCancelSubscriptionRoute() throws Exception {
  cancelSubscriptionTORMQUriEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper=    objectMapperContextResolver.getContext(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);
    String jsonString=objectMapper.writeValueAsString(subscription);

CancelSubscription cancelSubscription=cancelSubscriptionTransformer.toKbCancelSubscription(subscription);

Assert.assertEquals("mock auto created by       amel",cancelSubscription.getComment()); 

cancelSubscriptionFromRMQUriEndpoint.sendBody("         {{cancelSubscriptionFromRMQUri}}",jsonString);
   cancelSubscriptionTORMQUriEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
  }
}
```

The  Assert.assertEquals("mock auto created by       amel",cancelSubscription.getComment());  gets statisfied by calling cancelSubscriptionTransformer.toKbCancelSubscription which is invoked on the mock bean. however when message is sent to cancelSubscriptionFromRMQUriEndpoint.sendBody, the route is invoked and the actual beans in the route are not being replaced by mock beans

Comment: Please provide more information (source code, configuration, exceptions, ...) : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MickaëlB looks like the issue was I was not extending the correct bean and also I had to use @Inject in my route builder spring bean and use bean name instead of string format of bean name

Answer (score 0):

This is very old but I ran into this issue.

The answer is that instead of `.Bean(MyBean.class, "myMethod")`, you should use `.to("bean:myBean?method=myMethod")`. The reason is that the first way, Camel will instantiate the bean. The 2nd way, Spring has control of the bean and camel will look it up. Therefore you can use Spring mockBean to change it.

I'm using Camel version 3 now by the way, and beanRef is removed. If you used beanRef, replace it with `.to("bean:myBean?method=myMethod)`.